# When updating a salt-minion the grains.host changes to localhost, breaking states

Tags: salt-stack

Scenario:

- salt-minion original version: salt-minion 2015.8.8.2 (Beryllium)
- salt-minion updated version: salt-minion 2016.11.2 (Carbon)
- running a state which uses `grains.host` breaks

Checks:

- `salt 'minion' grains.item host` originally returned the hostname configured in `/etc/hostname` (eg: minion)
- After the update, it returns `localhost`

I tried restarting the minion (as I had to change the master url anyway), also tried the undocumented [`sanitized=True`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.item), which only hides it away.

Any help is appreciated, couldn't find anything on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found recently that sometimes it does matter what are your settings in `/etc/hosts`.

I had a set of hosts with FQDN like `host01.company.com`. And despite the same settings, one of them was having the same issues like you have. I went to `/etc/hosts` and removed record like

```
127.0.0.1 host01 host01.company.com
```

And after this and a minion restart, everything was fine immediately.

Looks like there is some kind of reverse-lookup happening to set some grains.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For now, sadly it was "fixed" by restarting the server, so I'm unable to test your approach, however I had changed the hosts file as it had localhost and move the server hostname to the first line, but didn't help, should have probably removed it as you did, although we do need it for other configurations.